# Filter and Query formulas not working properly in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a problem with google sheets, where sometimes the filter function (green square) won't work in some rows, always the last ones, but not always the same quantity. Sometimes will load all of them, sometimes none. It doesn't throw an error, just leave blank cells.

Other error is with the query on the blue square, it has no conditions (its just =query(range) cause I want to bring all the data) the problem is what you see on yellow background (the yellow is just a conditional format), there is data to bring on the right, but doesn't load it on the left, it is just weird. Sometimes I load the formula again and it will load more rows, sometimes less rows.

Can you tell me if there is some way to solve it? it is just 150 rows, and I've worked with 1000 or more with these formulas, and over 12000 with query and filter.

Thanks in advance.

The pic:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I had activated the iterative calculations on the Spreadsheet for some tests. It appears it limits the capacity of iteration of filter an query formulas.

Now it works like Christmas.

Thanks community